# How to search the projects with TFS Team Explorer?

Tags: tfs, team-explorer

Is there a way for me to locate the project inside the TFS, using the Team Explorer or whatever way by a search? I know the project name but don't know the exact path.

Answer (score 3):

If you install Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015/2013/2012 Power Tools from Visual Studio [gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=User&f%5B0%5D.Value=TFS%20Power%20Tools%20Team) you'll have the **Find in Source Control** option that will search through the file names in source control.

Comment: I've installed the Power Tools. Where can I find this option?

Comment: Right click on folder in the Source Control window then click Find, Find by Wildcard